# Django rest framework add model method to serializer twice

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I understand that it is possible to add a models method or property to a serializer, like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...

    def tax_status(self, check_item_bought=True):
        ...
```

So, to add `total_tax` to an `OrderSerializer`, it is as simple as this:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    tax_status = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ["tax_status", ...]
```

The above works well. However, I need to add another `tax_status_all` field to the serializer that points to the same method but setting the arg `check_item_bought`to False. How can I do this? Any advice will help.

Answer (score 5):

For this goal you can use [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    tax_status = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    tax_status_all = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ("tax_status", "tax_status_all")

    def get_tax_status_all(self, obj):  # "get_" + field name
        return obj.tax_status(check_item_bought=False)
```